# how to do datatable filter using jsf?

Tags: java, jsf

I want to do the filter in data table using jsf.In the datatable i have to filter the values what ever in the datatable.

There is first dropdown and based on the drop down second drop drow will enable with value.Based on the that values display in the datatable.

Could you give me some sample ot ideas.Please....

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to you to use prepared components for JSF

Try [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org).

They have a table with an option to  filter.

See a demo of database with the filter option [here](http://primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf)

Answer (score 1):

Try AJAX.  When the first selection fires off an event, make an AJAX call back to a service to query the database for the second drop down values using the selected value.